# How to unchain my program?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a simple chat program on java. 
I build it as maven project in IntelliJ Idea.
In the java dir i have 3 packages with 4 classes

```
|client
|---Client.class
|main
|---Main.class
|---Constants.class
|server
|---Server.class
```

When i start program I can choose in wich mode to start it (as server or as client).Multi user chat with 1 server to connect.

So, now i need to "unchain" my program.
I mean to make program structure as

```
ConsoleUI---AppLogic---TransportLayer(on sockets)
```

I need to do it with interfaces.What is it I don't know.
Can you help me. What can read such newbiee to get understanding of what's going on, how to realize it in the context of my program...

Comment: This is not something that can be easily explained. It is something that grows out of experience and learning. And If you really don't know what "interfaces" mean in Java; well; then I wholeheartedly recommend you to turn back to your desk and study books/tutorials on the essential Java basics. You are basically asking: "please help me driving my car from Paris to Moscow"; but it seems that you are yet not able to start the engine of your car.

Comment: yep, seems like that. :) Gonna go to the books